# Is it possible to cut video data without damaging the video format?

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, filereader

Let's say i have a bit longer video, like 50mb of size with duration of 2 minutes aprox for example, and i want to minimize his weight to make some metadata analizyng with server side code before uploading it to server (i'm using nodejs for that).

I need to do this thing because the browsers decided that they will don't display util information of an uploaded file with pure javascript.

I mean, some information like **type** is only working if the file has his specific extension at the end of his name, otherwise will only displays an empty string which is stupid, and for security reasons the pathname of the file is always empty.

And i want to use:

```
FileReader.readAsDataUrl(file);
```

method to upload this data to a server when is already analyzed and checked his extension in node server side.

But this have two main problems:

- FileReader.readAsDataUrl() method only works fine if the file has his extension at the end of the file, otherwise the base64 encoded data is a base64 encoded string but his data: value is `application/octet-stream` which is an extremely unsafe format to allow in **php** yeah i'm analyzing with node before passing the entire data to php (if the file pass the allowed format test) so nodejs only takes the role of analyzer in this case.
- I don't want to upload the entire file to be analyzed in node this is inefficient and slow, i want to upload for example if is a video, the first second of a video, and if is possible only the 0.01 seconds of the video, which i don't know if this is possible. And then upload it to an specific separated nodejs folder which will take the analysis and retrieve a response that contains the myme-type of the file.

The problem is that i don't know how to determine which are the minimum neccessary bytes of data that the file needs to not be damaged. and i don't know how to determine it, so first question, it's possible to determine it whitout damaging the file?

i tried first using slice method of the uploaded file:

```
File.slice(0, 50000);
```

But this is test an error, to know that the file needs first 50000 bytes to not be damaged and can be reproduced if i use later `URL.createObjectURL(slicedFile)` and opening the result url, in my case if i put the first 50000 bytes of info is reproducing only the first second which is the desired behavior (video clipped correctly).

- It is possible to determine what is the minimum amount of bytes to cut the first second video without damaging it?
- If isn't possible with some of the methods above... anyone have an idea to do this thing?
- Audio files are a caos to analyze where is his metadata if i print FileReader.readAsText(); some files has his metadata explicitly specified in the binary data in the start of the file, but some times this is not the case... what should i do?

Comment: Ah also i need to say that i'm working in linux ubuntu, so i think this makes the things a bit easier if it's needed to run some shell script.

Comment: “application/octet-stream which is an extremely unsafe format to allow in php” isn’t true.

Comment: assuming application/octet-stream is secure, can php determine what type of content is? (mime-type) without using the $File variable?, (because the application i'm deveolping is a mobile web based app, but the provider that can make a post request only allows to send header types and the content like a rest API an later use json-decode function to obtain contents in php file). also can be determined with php like this?